# How to build from the source?

Tags: python, build, sqlite

I cannot use sqlite3 (build python package). The reason of the is missing _sqlite3.so. I found that peoples had the same problem and they resolved it [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/no-sqlite3.so-in-usrlibpython2.5lib-dynload-599027/).

The solutions is given in one sentence:

> By building from source and moving the
>   library to
>   /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/ I
>   resolved the issue.

However, I do t understand the terminology. What does it mean "building from the source"? What should be build from the source? New version of Python? SQLite? And how one actually build from the source? Which steps should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the SQLite source here: [SQLite Download Page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Extract the tarball somewhere on your machine.

Navigate to the expanded directory.

Run:

```
./configure
make
make install (sudo make install if you have permission issues)
```

Copy the newly compiled files to your Python directory.

Those directions are the simplest possible. You may run into dependency issues in which case, you'll need to download and build them as well.